# converting a Cygwin path a a path that ruby can understand

Tags: ruby, bash, cygwin, jruby

In my scrip I have a section that needs to change a local path name into an absolute path(not going in to it, sorry)

I am using

```
args+="-f "
args+="$(realpath "$relative-path") "
jruby -Ilib bin/trace.rb $args
```

This works for things inside the script, but when I pass this absolute file path to ruby, it does not know what to do. I can think of ways to fix this problem on my local box through string substitution.
sub (C: for cygpath/c), but if I were to deploy my script to an unknown file system I could be in trouble. 
it needs to work on cygwin for development (I know I have to develop in widows) and unix boxes.

Question:

Is the a way that I can make my script always pass a usable path as an arg to ruby (jruby but that should not matter).

advice for a single solution or one tackles the cygwin and unix environments differently are both welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cygwin's `cygpath` command is the tool for the job. It converts between Cygwin's POSIX paths and various forms of Windows paths. It will even do the absolute path conversion for you, so:

```
args+="$(cygpath -wa "$relative-path") "
```

See cygpath's help output or man page for details on its options.

Answer (score 1):

[@ak2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895922/converting-a-cygwin-path-a-a-path-that-ruby-can-understand/7900022#7900022) has the right answer. You would be better off using an array to build up the arguments though, especially if the path has a space:

```
args=(-f)
args+=("$(cygpath -wa "$relative-path")")
jruby -Ilib bin/trace.rb "${args[@]}"
```